# usbmount does not unmount vfat mount point

Tags: linux, usb, mount, raspbian, debian-buster

I use usbmount to automatically mount usb drives. Everything works fine for my external SSD with four NTFS partitions. They are mountend when the external drive is connected and automatically unmounted when the external drive is disconnected.
Also the usb stick with one FAT32 partition is mounted automatically, but usbmount does not unmount this drive. This leads to a blocking of the mount point.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically unmounted when the external drive is disconnected"? In general [one should unmount *before* unplugging](https://superuser.com/q/180722/432690). I haven't tested this (yet) but it seems plausible that inability to unmount *may* be because there are open descriptors or data waiting to be written.

Comment: I know that unmounting BEFORE unplugging would be the better solution. But incase you unplugg first, usbmount should free the mountpoint. This works for NTFS partitions but not for FAT32 partitions.